# pyspark PCA in EMR Jupyter Notebook returning "error payload: {"msg":"requirement failed: Session isn't active."}" error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter, amazon-emr, apache-spark-ml

I'm reading in something like 10,000 images (3x100x100 pixels) into a pyspark dataframe which then undergoes StandardScaling and then PCA reduction to 10 dimensions.
The standardscaling works fine but the PCA step always fails. I thought it was a maxresultsize error, so I increased to 4g but still getting this pesky error :

```
    An error was encountered:
Invalid status code '400' from https://172.31.12.39:18888/sessions/0/statements/9 with error payload: {"msg":"requirement failed: Session isn't active."}
```

[image]

The code I'm using is to execute the PCA is :

```
 pca = PCA(k=10, inputCol="scaledvecs", outputCol="pcavecs")
model = pca.fit(scaledData)
reduced_data = model.transform(scaledData).select("pcavecs")
```

The EMR cluster is composed of 1 master node and 10 workers, all m5.xlarge which should be sufficient.

Any ideas ?

Comment: have you managed to solve this? as I am encountering the same error

Comment: Had to increase the memory of the spark configuration : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/modify-spark-configuration-emr-notebook/